# loop if conditions are met and append values to vector, else skip to next

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, unique

I am relatively new to R, please pardon if my question is not entirely clear :)

I start with 2 lists (one (ftyes) is screen capped here). I have a function called “ksauto”, which for an entry in the “category” column, performs a Kolmogorov–Smirnov (ks) test to compare the corresponding values under column “log2fc” in the 2 lists. The function also sums how many entries there are for each category.

I have written a loop to run the function for each unique entry under “category”, and append the output to vectors, from which I’ll make a table. The problem is that, for certain entries under “category” e.g. catE, one of the list contains only NA values, which creates a problem for the ks test and stops the loop. I want to write an IF clause to exclude those entries, but couldn’t get it to work.

The function:

```
          ksauto <- function(i){
#picks out entries with i in both lists
          subyes <<- ftyes[ftyes$category== i,]  
          subno <<- ftno[ftno$category== i,]  
#save output values
          name <<- toString(i)
          ks <<- round(ks.test(subyes$FC,subno$FC)$p.value,digits=5)
          yescpe <<- sum(ftyes$category == i)
          nocpe <<- sum(ftno$category == i)
          }
```

The loop:

```
for(i in unique(bpyes$name_1006)) 
      {
#runs function for each unique i, append output to vector
      ksauto(i)
      vname[i] <- name
      vks[i] <- ks
      vyescpe[i] <- yescpe
      vnocpe[i] <- nocpe
      }
```

I have the IF clause like this:

```
((sum(!is.na(subyes$FC)) != 0 )&( sum(!is.na(subno$FC)) != 0 ))
```

I tried putting it in the function and switching the logical argument to an OR clause, also adding the next and else commands to the IF clause, but nothing worked. It would be great if I get some input. Thank you for your time!!

[example of one of two lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwcfm.jpg)

Best,

Wilson

Comment: see `?try` and `?tryCatch`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess without data so I don't know if it will work. Note that reshaping doesn't work with list variables :( Let me know if if is guaranteed that for each name, subyes$FC and subno$FC will have exactly the same number of values. This would make things a whole lot easier.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

unique_name = bpyes %>% select(name = name_1066) %>% distinct

yes_summary = 
  unique_name %>%
  left_join(subyes %>% rename(name = category) ) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(yes_count = n(),
            yes_FC_list = list(FC)) %>%
  filter(yes_count > 0)

no_summary = 
  unique_name %>%
  left_join(subno %>% rename(name = category) ) %>%
  rename(name = category) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(no_count = n(),
            no_FC_list = list(FC))  %>%
  filter(no_count > 0)

result = 
  inner_join(yes_summary, no_summary) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(ks = ks.test(no_FC_list, yes_FC_list) %>%
                use_series(p.value) %>%
                round(digits = 5) ) %>%
  select(-no_FC_list, -yes_FC_list)
```

Comment: there's quite some commands I'm not familiar with yet. I'll test that out. Thanks very much!